# How to delete ONLY m2m relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

model:

```
class Province(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, editable=False, unique=False)
    ownership = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserCity')


class UserCity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)


class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)
    ownership = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserDistrict')

class UserDistrict(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
```

How can I delete relation when I know user_id and province_id? If i user delete() method it also removes province and I want to avoid it. I can't find anywhere how to delete 1 specific relation in m2m field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the remove method on your [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) manager.

```
Province.objects.get(id=3).user.remove(user_id)
```

---

You can also access the through table directly if you so desire:

```
Province.user.through.objects.get(province__id=3, user__id=4).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks - both methods works. As I see it doesn't remove any other relations which I declared - city-province, city-district. I guess I must do it manually.

Comment: NP: is there a problem left? I thought you specifically didn't want to delete the other relations?

Comment: hehe, I want to delete all relations based on that described. When I delete province-user relation, I want all other relations to be deleted. I updated my post and there are all my tables. Is it possible to delete other relations automatically or I must do it by hand?

Comment: You will have to delete the others with a custom function that takes a user_id and deletes what it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete only the relationship for all instance between 2 models then you can do that by accessing the Manager of the relationship table. The m2m relationship table can be accessed via `MyModel.relations.through` so for deleting the relationships it becomes easy:

```
MyModel.relations.through.objects.all().delete()
```

reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old...
If you want to delete all the `users` of a specific `province`:

```
province.user.clear()
```